# Sending message using C# and Godaddy mail server is not working RSS

Tags: c#, email

The below code is working fine all data stored in DB very well, but the problem is at the end of the code by sending email to user where it not sending any email at all to other mail server such as Hotmail, yahoo, gmail, ....

```
 protected void adNewQdadsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileExtentio = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(RegInteFileUploadImg1.FileName);
        string FileExtentio2 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(RegInteFileUploadImg2.FileName);
        string FileExtentio3 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(RegInteFileUploadImg3.FileName);
        string FileExtentio4 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(RegInteFileUploadImg4.FileName);
        string FileExtentio5 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(RegInteFileUploadImg5.FileName);


        string makervalue = string.Empty;
        string Yearvalue = string.Empty;
        string Gearvalue = string.Empty;
        string RoomNum = string.Empty;
        string BathNum = string.Empty;
        string garageNum = string.Empty;
        string areasize = string.Empty;
        string QUAD = "Q";
        string AdsAprov = "N";
        string NyAdsDesc = TextBox2.Text;

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");
        string Location = string.Empty;
        Location = cookie.Value;



        switch (RegCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text)
        {
            case "Cars":
                // Set your values
                makervalue = RegRebarndcardrlst1.SelectedValue;
                Yearvalue = RegCarYearfrmDrDw.SelectedValue;
                Gearvalue = RegDropDownList4.SelectedValue;
                break;
            case "Trucks":
                // Set your values
                makervalue = RegDropDownList9.SelectedValue;
                Yearvalue = RegDropDownList12.SelectedValue;
                Gearvalue = RegDropDownList10.SelectedValue;
                break;
            case "Tractor":
                // Set your values
                makervalue = RegDropDownList3.SelectedValue;
                Yearvalue = RegDropDownList5.SelectedValue;
                Gearvalue = RegDropDownList7.SelectedValue;
                break;
            case "Airplane":
                // Set your values
                makervalue = RegDropDownList8.SelectedValue;
                Yearvalue = RegDropDownList6.SelectedValue;
                // Should you be setting Gearvalue here?
                break;

            case "Apartment":
            case "Villa":
            case "Office":
                // Set your values
                RoomNum = RegAddAdsRomDDL.SelectedValue;
                BathNum = RegshowersNumDDL.SelectedValue;
                garageNum = ReggarageNumddl.SelectedValue;
                areasize = RegAreaSizeDDL.SelectedValue;

                break;


            default:
                // Consider throwing an error here, none of your options were selected
                break;
        }


            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);


                if (RegInteFileUploadImg1.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg2.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg3.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg4.HasFile || RegInteFileUploadImg5.HasFile)
                {


                    var files = new[] { FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, FileExtentio3, FileExtentio4, FileExtentio5 };
                    files = files.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
                    var extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".png" };
                    if ((files.Except(extensions).Count()) <= 0)
                    {
                        if (RegDropDownList3.SelectedValue == "no")
                        {
                            AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                            adsstutslbel.Text = "- Please select ads status";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }


                        if (DropDownList11.SelectedValue == "no")
                        {
                            AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                            adscondlbel.Text = "- Please select ads condition";
                        }


                        string sqlstatment = @"INSERT INTO ads(Section, Category, AdsTit, AdsDesc, Country, State,AdsDate, City, AdsPrice, Img1, img2, img3, img4,img5, Wtags, QAdsTeleNum,Condition, Status,Maker,Year,Gear,RoomNo, Space,Shower,Garage,Currency,extlink,AdType,approvAds,QAdsEmail,Address) VALUES (@Section, @Category, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Img1, @img2, @img3, @img4, @img5, @Wtags, @QAdsTeleNum,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage,@Currency, @extlink,@AdType,@approvAds,@QAdsEmail,@Address)";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstatment, cn);


                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", RegSecdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maker", makervalue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Yearvalue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gear", Gearvalue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", RoomNum);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Space", areasize);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", RegCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", NyAdsDesc);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cookie.Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", Regstatedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", Regcitiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsPrice", adsaddpristxtbx.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsTeleNum", QuickAdsMobNumTxtBox.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shower", BathNum);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Garage", garageNum);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtags", addadswtagtxtbtn.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition", DropDownList11.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList13.SelectedValue);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adsDate", DateTime.Now);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", AddAdsCurencyLBL.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extlink", extlinktxtbox.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdType", QUAD);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@approvAds", AdsAprov);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsEmail", QuickAdsEmailTxtBox.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", EditAdsAddrsTxtBox.Text);

                        string imgnouser = "/images/general/nouser.jpg";

                        if (RegInteFileUploadImg1.HasFile)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", RegInteFileUploadImg1.FileName);
                            RegInteFileUploadImg1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + RegInteFileUploadImg1.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (RegInteFileUploadImg2.HasFile)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", RegInteFileUploadImg2.FileName);
                            RegInteFileUploadImg2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + RegInteFileUploadImg2.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (RegInteFileUploadImg3.HasFile)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img3", RegInteFileUploadImg3.FileName);
                            RegInteFileUploadImg3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + RegInteFileUploadImg3.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img3", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (RegInteFileUploadImg4.HasFile)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img4", RegInteFileUploadImg4.FileName);
                            RegInteFileUploadImg4.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + RegInteFileUploadImg4.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img4", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (RegInteFileUploadImg5.HasFile)
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img5", RegInteFileUploadImg5.FileName);
                            RegInteFileUploadImg5.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + RegInteFileUploadImg5.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img5", imgnouser);
                        }


                        cn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.Text = "Error: The file should have .png or .jpg format only";
                        AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                        return;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    string sqlstatment2 = @"INSERT INTO ads(Section, Category, AdsTit, AdsDesc, Country, State,AdsDate, City, AdsPrice, Wtags, QAdsTeleNum,Condition, Status,Maker,Year,Gear,RoomNo, Space,Shower,Garage,extlink,AdType,approvAds,QAdsEmail,Address) VALUES (@Section, @Category, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Wtags, @QAdsTeleNum,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage, @extlink,@AdType,@approvAds,@QAdsEmail,@Address)";


                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstatment2, cn);

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", RegSecdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maker", makervalue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Yearvalue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gear", Gearvalue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", RoomNum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Space", areasize);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", RegCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", NyAdsDesc);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cookie.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", Regstatedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", Regcitiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsPrice", adsaddpristxtbx.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsTeleNum", QuickAdsMobNumTxtBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shower", BathNum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Garage", garageNum);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtags", addadswtagtxtbtn.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition", DropDownList11.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList13.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adsDate", DateTime.Now);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", AddAdsCurencyLBL.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extlink", extlinktxtbox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdType", QUAD);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@approvAds", AdsAprov);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsEmail", QuickAdsEmailTxtBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", EditAdsAddrsTxtBox.Text);

                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

                string QAdsID = string.Empty;
                string QADSTit = string.Empty;
                string QADSUsrEm= string.Empty;

                using (SqlCommand SendMailcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT AdsID,AdsTit,QAdsEmail FROM ads WHERE AdsTit=@AdsTit AND Section=@Section AND Category=@Category AND Status=@Status AND AdsPrice=@AdsPrice AND Condition=@Condition AND AdsDesc=@AdsDesc"))
                {
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", RegSecdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", RegCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsPrice", adsaddpristxtbx.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList13.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition", DropDownList11.SelectedItem.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                    SendMailcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QAdsEmail", QuickAdsEmailTxtBox.Text.Trim());

                    SendMailcmd.Connection = cn;

                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = SendMailcmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            QAdsID = sdr["AdsID"].ToString();
                            QADSTit = sdr["AdsTit"].ToString();
                            QADSUsrEm = sdr["QAdsEmail"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QAdsID))
                {
                    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("donotreply@berava.com", QuickAdsEmailTxtBox.Text.Trim());
                    mm.Subject = "Berava - Edit Ad";
                    mm.Body = string.Format("Hello there<br /><br />We are so happy using Berava, now you can edit or delete your ads by click on below link:<br /><a href = '" + "http://www.berava.com/EditAds.aspx?AID=" + QAdsID + "&QADSTit=" + QADSTit + "'>Click here to edit or delete.</a><br /><br />If you have any inquiries please do not hesitate to contact us via our contact form at Berava.com, or you can send it on: info@berava.com<br /><br /> Have a happy time with Berava.<br /><br />Berava team<br /><br /><a href ='www.berava.com'><img src='http://www.berava.com/images/general/Berava-logo.png'></a>", QAdsID, QADSTit);

                    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
                    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential();
                    NetworkCred.UserName = "donotreply@berava.com";
                    NetworkCred.Password = "";
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                    smtp.Port = 80;
                    smtp.Send(mm);
                    //Response.Redirect("Berava.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Response.Redirect("EditAds.aspx?QADID=" + QAdsID + "&QADSTit=" + QADSTit);
                }

                addadswtagtxtbtn.Text = "";
                QuickAdsEmailTxtBox.Text = "";
                QuickAdsMobNumTxtBox.Text = "";
                extlinktxtbox.Text = "";
                adsaddpristxtbx.Text = "";
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                addadstittxtbx.Text = "";

                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;

    }
```

Comment: smtp.EnableSsl = true;

Comment: @Stuart i have tried but is the same it not sending email.

Comment: @Stuart i have did as you mention and i delete port:80 but it's same nothing solved, but in other pages of my web application i have used the same port where is 80 and its working.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, from what I have read from their docs it's either port 80 or 3535. But I'm not convinced this is your issue